# How can I distinguish a multi-occurence option from a subsequent optional argument with structopt?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, structopt

I am using structopt to define arguments that can be used

```
mfe -s opt1 -s opt2 -s opt2 this_is_an_argument
```

or

```
mfe -s opt1 opt2 opt3 this_is_an_argument
```

The problem is that the `this_is_an_argument` argument is parsed as an option. I know I could use `--` before the argument, but is there a better solution?

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct CLIArgs {
    #[structopt(short = "s", long = "str")]
    strings: Vec<String>,

    #[structopt(name = "PATH", parse(from_os_str))]
    path: Option<PathBuf>,
}

fn main() {
    let args = CLIArgs::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

```
$ mfe -s foo bar baz /this/is/a/path
CLIArgs { strings: ["foo", "bar", "baz", "/this/is/a/path"], path: None }
```

I would like `/this/is/a/path` to be parsed as `path`, without being forced to use `--`. Maybe do something with the order of the arguments or something?

Comment: what's wrong with using `--`?

Comment: How do **you**, the programmer, know that ` this/is/a/path` isn't part of the `-s` option? There's nothing blindingly obvious. Equally importantly, how will a user of your program know?

Answer (score 2):

So I found the following solution:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct CLIArgs {
    #[structopt(short = "s", long = "str", raw(number_of_values = "1"))]
    strings: Vec<String>,

    #[structopt(name = "PATH", parse(from_os_str))]
    path: Option<PathBuf>,
}

fn main() {
    let args = CLIArgs::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

Note that it forces the user to use the program this way:

```
$ mfe -s foo -s bar -s baz /this/is/a/path
```

which my be inconvenient, depending on your use case.

Comment: In later versions `number_of_values` can be added as a number argument to structopt: `#[structopt(short = "s", long = "str", number_of_values=1)]`